# Managing State when Passing React Component Constuctor Function to Another Component as Attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a React component constructor function to another component, which should have a setState event handler. How should I bind "this" to the handler?

This is the App component, which has data as state, like this:

```
const App = function(props, context) {
    this.props = props;
    this.context = context;
};

App.prototype = Object.create(React.Component.prototype);
App.prototype.state = {
    datum: [
        {
            isTicked: true,
            otherData: "otherData_1"
            /* Other data inside object */
        },
        {
            isTicked: false,
            otherData: "otherData_2"
            /* Other data inside object */
        },
        {
            isTicked: true,
            otherData: "otherData_3"
            /* Other data inside object */
        }
    ]
};
```

And here is the Table component constructs the components based on the callbacks on `props.row` like this:

index.js:

```
// index.js
const Table = require("./table.js");
```

table.js:

```
// table.js
module.exports = (props, context) => (
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>{Object.keys(props.row).map(k => <th>{k}</th>)}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {props.datum.map((obj, index) => (
                <tr>
                    {Object.keys(props.row).map(k => (
                        <td>
                            {props.row[k] instanceof Function
                                ? props.row[k](obj, index)
                                : props.row[k]}
                        </td>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
    </table>
);
```

I pass down `props.row` like this:

```
App.prototype.tableRow = {
    T: (data, index) => (
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={data.isTicked}
            onChange={e => {
                this.setState(prevState => {
                    prevState.datum[index].isTicked = !prevState.datum[index]
                        .isTicked;
                    return {
                        datum: prevState.datum
                    };
                });
            }}
        />
    ),
    otherData: data => data.otherData
};

App.prototype.render = function() {
    return <Table datum={this.state.datum} row={this.tableRow} />;
};
```

The problem here is that when I pass the `props.row` a callback function that constructs a React element which should call `this.setState` on an `onClick` event, I cannot bind `this` as a usual event handler function.

Here is my CodeSandBox example which shows this situation:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jjlvvwjvpv
You can see, if you click the checkboxes it signals, `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'undefined.setState')`, which indicates this evaluates to undefined.

How should I handle `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could resolve this issue by revising your `App.prototype.tableRow` object to the following:

```
App.prototype.tableRow = {
  T: function(data, index) {  /* <--- Use regular function here, rather than arrow function */

    return <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={data.isTicked}
      onChange={e => {

        this.setState(prevState => {
          prevState.datum[index].isTicked = !prevState.datum[index].isTicked;
          return {
            datum: prevState.datum
          };
        });
      }}
    />
  },
  otherData: data => data.otherData
};
```

And then, update your render function like so:

```
App.prototype.render = function() {

  /* Clone the tableRow object from prototype, and bind T function to this instance */
  const tableRow = { ...this.tableRow };  
  tableRow.T = tableRow.T.bind(this);

  return <Table datum={this.state.datum} row={tableRow} />;
};
```

Here's [a working demo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ym4jrvpjj) - hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!! It helped me a lot! I would like to upvote but I don't have 15 reputation ;-( Anyway, Thank you!!

Comment: @조성빈 you're welcome - thank you for that, that's okay, glad I could help you :-)